# How can i use the decoded json data when the first index data is very large in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2, laravel-6.2

After decoding the **json** data i am getting these value and i want to use these separately to show it in the textbox for updating these data.
but i cannot get any way to do it.

[image]

i am encoding it as below in the controller

```
$data = json_encode(array(
                $request->question1 => $request->answer1,
                $request->question2 => $request->answer2,
                $request->question3 => $request->answer3,
                $request->question4 => $request->answer4
            ));
```

`@php $data = json_decode($contact_us->key_value); @endphp` 
i want to do it in the view to show it in the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(json_decode($data) as $x) {
    echo $x;
}
```

Access the individual properties by using a foreach

To both key and value

```
foreach(json_decode($data) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' ' . $value;
}
```

Comment: also use key values in the foreach if you want the key

Comment: Thank you ,but this will recursively access all the data, but i want to access one at a time for different text fields.